# While loop in logging filter breaks Django server

Tags: python, django

I wanted to add a filter to the python logger in my Django project; the filter has a while loop in it (there to wait and allow the user to provide a response).  However, when I try to implement my filter the server seems to immediately break and my view goes into an infinite loop (which doesn't happen when I test the filter in a terminal window).

My code I have looks like this:

```
import logging, time, os

# in my Utils.py file:
def ErrorReport(msg, notify=False, warnOnly=False):
  logger.exception("ErrorReport:%s" % msg, exc_info=True)
  raise RuntimeError('Aborting execution. Terrible things might happen. Check logs for more information')

# in my views.py file:
class ErrorFilter(logging.Filter):
  def __init__(self,level):
    self.level = level
    print level

  def filter(self,record):
    if record.levelno == self.level:
        os.environ["ERROR_FLAG"] = "True"
        timeout = time.time() + 60*1 #set the timeout to 1 minute
        while True:
            print "waiting..."
            keep_going = os.environ.get("CONTINUE_FLAG")
            #wait for user to respond
            if keep_going == "False" or time.time() > timeout:
                Utils.ErrorReport("There's a problem, quiting current process.")
            if keep_going == "True":
                break

logger     = Utils.getLogger() #I format the logger in another python script called Utils
logger.addFilter(ErrorFilter(logging.ERROR)) 

def home(request):
  context_dict = {'boldmessage': "--> To view logs, please turn off any popup blockers <--",'version':"1.1.6"}
  logger.error("faking an error to test new filter")
  return render(request, 'InterfaceApp/home.html', context_dict)
```

I've tested a simpler version of this filter in a terminal window and didn't have any problems with it getting stuck in an infinite loop.  When I try to open the home page of my django site it looks like it's loading forever, and when I look at the developers window I can see that I've lost the connection to my server.  In the terminal window where I'm running the server, I get the print statement `waiting...` forever, even though I've set and tested the timeout on the while loop.

Is there a fundamental problem with running `while` loops in a django project, or have I missed something?

Comment: No, the fundamental problem is with getting your logger to ask for user input.

Comment: @DanielRoseman all it's supposed to do is check a flag value until the timer runs out.  I've gotten this to work in a non-web environment.

Comment: Well, are you sure that CONTINUE_FLAG is set at all, and that it is one of "True" or "False"? And how does Utils.ErrorReport "quit the current process"?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It isn't set initially, so I put the timeout in there in case it remains `None`, but the timeout doesn't seem to be working in Django.  I have other views that set the value of `CONTINUE_FLAG` to either "True" or "False".  I edited the code to include the `Utils.ErrorReport` function.

Comment: Is the `logger` in ErrorReport the same as the one returned from Utils.getLogger? ie does it have the same filter?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it shouldn't be raising a RuntimeError unless the flag is set to "False" or the loop times out after 1 minute.  My server quits immediately and the `while` loop runs indefinitely.  If for some reason it is going into the quit if statement immediately, shouldn't it stop the while loop as well?  And yes, it is the same logger and therefore I think it has the same filter

Comment: The flag will *never* go to False, because your other view must necessarily be in another process; and your timeout is actually six seconds, not a minute. But nevertheless, can you answer my question about the logger in ErrorReport?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97308/discussion-between-kdubs-and-daniel-roseman).